# How i can add an Image as my header in a word document using Apache POI

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

I am trying create an word  document using Apache POI which will contains an image as its header and some information ,i.e paragraph as its footer.I am able to create the header footer with paragraph only.But i need to add the image to the header which i can not manage,I am posting my code here which is correctly giving the result as the header footer both with the paragraph.Somebody please help me to reach this,

```
public class CreateWordDoc {

public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {


    //XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
    CustomXWPFDocument document = new CustomXWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\test.docx")));
    CTP ctp = CTP.Factory.newInstance();
    CTR ctr = ctp.addNewR();
    CTRPr rpr = ctr.addNewRPr();
    CTText textt = ctr.addNewT();
    textt.setStringValue( " Client Service Contact:Tomas.Layrisse@mshgroupconsulting.com" );
    XWPFParagraph codePara = new XWPFParagraph( ctp, document );
    XWPFParagraph imagePara = new XWPFParagraph(ctp, document);

    XWPFParagraph[] newparagraphs = new XWPFParagraph[1];
    newparagraphs[0] = codePara;
    XWPFParagraph[] imaheparagraphs = new XWPFParagraph[1];
    imaheparagraphs[0]=imagePara;
    String blipId = document.addPictureData(new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\msh.jpg")), Document.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG);
    CTSectPr sectPr = document.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr();
    XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy headerFooterPolicy = new  XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy( document, sectPr );

    document.createPicture(blipId,document.getNextPicNameNumber(Document.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG), 400, 129);


    headerFooterPolicy.createHeader( STHdrFtr.FIRST,imaheparagraphs);
    //headerFooterPolicy.createFooter( STHdrFtr.DEFAULT, newparagraphs );
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("D:\\test.docx");
    document.write(out);
    System.out.println("Doc Created");

   }
}
```

my modofications

```
XWPFParagraph[] imaheparagraphs = new XWPFParagraph[1];
    r.addPicture(new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\msh.jpg")), Document.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG, "D:\\msh.jpg", 21, 32);
    r=imagePara.createRun();
    imaheparagraphs[0]=imagePara;

    String blipId = document.addPictureData(new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\msh.jpg")), Document.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG);
    CTSectPr sectPr = document.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr();
    XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy headerFooterPolicy = new  XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy( document, sectPr );

    document.createPicture(blipId,document.getNextPicNameNumber(Document.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG), 400, 129);


    headerFooterPolicy.createHeader( STHdrFtr.DEFAULT,imaheparagraphs);
```

.....................................................................................

```
public class CustomXWPFDocument extends XWPFDocument{

public CustomXWPFDocument(FileInputStream in) throws IOException
{
    super(in);
}

public void createPicture(String blipId,int id, int width, int height)
{
    final int EMU = 9525;
    width *= EMU;
    height *= EMU;
    //String blipId = getAllPictures().get(id).getPackageRelationship().getId();


    CTInline inline = createParagraph().createRun().getCTR().addNewDrawing().addNewInline();

    String picXml = "" +
            "<a:graphic xmlns:a=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main\">" +
            "   <a:graphicData uri=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture\">" +
            "      <pic:pic xmlns:pic=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture\">" +
            "         <pic:nvPicPr>" +
            "            <pic:cNvPr id=\"" + id + "\" name=\"Generated\"/>" +
            "            <pic:cNvPicPr/>" +
            "         </pic:nvPicPr>" +
            "         <pic:blipFill>" +
            "            <a:blip r:embed=\"" + blipId + "\" xmlns:r=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships\"/>" +
            "            <a:stretch>" +
            "               <a:fillRect/>" +
            "            </a:stretch>" +
            "         </pic:blipFill>" +
            "         <pic:spPr>" +
            "            <a:xfrm>" +
            "               <a:off x=\"0\" y=\"0\"/>" +
            "               <a:ext cx=\"" + width + "\" cy=\"" + height + "\"/>" +
            "            </a:xfrm>" +
            "            <a:prstGeom prst=\"rect\">" +
            "               <a:avLst/>" +
            "            </a:prstGeom>" +
            "         </pic:spPr>" +
            "      </pic:pic>" +
            "   </a:graphicData>" +
            "</a:graphic>";

    //CTGraphicalObjectData graphicData = inline.addNewGraphic().addNewGraphicData();
    XmlToken xmlToken = null;
    try
    {
        xmlToken = XmlToken.Factory.parse(picXml);
    }
    catch(XmlException xe)
    {
        xe.printStackTrace();
    }
    inline.set(xmlToken);
    //graphicData.set(xmlToken);

    inline.setDistT(0);
    inline.setDistB(0);
    inline.setDistL(0);
    inline.setDistR(0);

    CTPositiveSize2D extent = inline.addNewExtent();
    extent.setCx(width);
    extent.setCy(height);

    CTNonVisualDrawingProps docPr = inline.addNewDocPr();
    docPr.setId(id);
    docPr.setName("Picture " + id);
    docPr.setDescr("Generated");
   }
}
```

As of now the header is coming in the body of the doc ,please help,Thanks is advance.

Comment: I don't see any code adding the image in there? What happens if you [try to add the picture in to a run](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFRun.html#addPicture%28java.io.InputStream,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29) that's in one of the paragraphs in the header?

Comment: @Gagravarr i actually dont know how to add an image in the header,thats why i also mentioned that i  am able only to write a paragraph in the header,i image thing i have asked how to do

Comment: Try adding the image to a XWPFRun in the header, just as you would a XWPFRun in the main document, and see?

Comment: can you please give some hints please or  write some lines ??please

Comment: You need to attach the picture to the Run you want it to turn up in, see the link from my first comment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67401/discussion-between-lucifer-and-gagravarr).

Comment: @Gagravarr tell me one thing if i am able to add it in the run then how i will make the code understand that i  have to add that image in the header??

Comment: If you add the image to a run that's located in the header, then that run should know where it is so should know where to attach the image to!

Comment: can you write some code for me i have tried a lot but still not finding it.please can you please modify it please??

Comment: @Gagravarr can you see my latest update i have tried as you told but i am getting nullpointer in header

Comment: @Gagravarr also ttried this..FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("D:\\msh.jpg");
  imagePara.createRun().addPicture(fis, Document.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG, "msh.jpg", 400, 129);
  imaheparagraphs[0]=imagePara;

Comment: Is it solved..? If 'Yes' Please add the solution here..